# Integer Programming: Model uniqueness of integer variables

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Let's suppose to have three integer variables for integer programming, thus:

```
a \in {1,2,3}
b \in {1,2,3}
c \in {1,2,3}
```

Now I want to model that all variables are different. Obviously I can do the following for every combination (three in this case). I show it with a and b.

```
a <= b - 1 + bin1 * bigM
a >= b + 1 - (1 - bin1) * bigM
bin1 \in {0, 1}
```

Is there an easier way without producing lots of new constraints, bigMs, and binary variables?

Comment: I'm not aware of any better formulation with linear programming. I guess you can't since it's actually a combinatorial optimization problem. Constraint Programming solvers/languages implement global constraints, see [z3 Distinct](http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#aa79af225f3b27b84fef346c257d2e406) and [Minizinc all_different](http://www.minizinc.org/2.0/doc-lib/doc-globals-alldifferent.html) for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, not really. This construct is often called the `all-different constraint`. Here is a reference:

> H.P.Williams, Hong Yan, "*Representations of the all-different
>   Predicate of Constraint Satisfaction in Integer Programming*," INFORMS
>   Journal on Computing, Vol. 13 (2001) 96-103

See also the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1646846/set-up-an-integer-programming-problem-so-that-all-variables-in-the-solution-are).

Answer (score 1):

I found out, that one could do the following as well:

```
x_j   \in {1,2,3} for j \in {1,2,3}
b_i_j \in {0,1} for i,j \in {1,2,3}
\sum_{i=1}^{3} i * b_i_j = x_j for j \in {1,2,3}
\sum_{i=1}^{3} b_i_j = 1 for j \in {1,2,3}
```

Well, obviously there is `j^2` new binary variables now. But you have your `x_j` variables as well as your `b_i_j` variables thus you are much more flexible for all kind of constraints.

```
all-different constraint:
\sum_{j=1}^{3} b_i_j = 1 for i \in {1,2,3}
```

Seems okay, doesn't it?